# Contravariant binary operations in Scala

Tags: scala, category-theory

For a very basic generic model of categories, I'm trying to get the morphism associated with a pair of objects in a contravariant fashion.

```
class Obj[DerivedObj <: Obj[DerivedObj]] { /* ... */ }

class Morphism[DerivedMorphism <: Morphism[DerivedMorphism]] { /* ... */ }
```

I'd like to somehow be able to define:

```
def mor( from : SomeConcreteObj, to : SomeConcreteObj ) : SomeConcreteMorphism;
```

but the `obvious' solution of making mor a method of Obj would require Obj to be additionally type-parameterized by Morphism.

What's the Scala way of achieving such a thing?

Comment: Which of many possible morphisms `mor` should return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, bad entity relationship on my part. Presumably the implication is that mor is actually a method of some Category class:

```
trait Cat[O,M] {
   def mor( from : O, to : O ) : M;

}
```

which would seem to solve the problem.